# add string in dos / batch to filename

Tags: batch-file, dos

I didn't find anything here or on the net for this small question and I have no idea how to do it.

Assume that you have under windows/DOS the following file:
**filename.ext**

You want to make a copy this file in the same directory. The copy should have the name:
**filename.AA.ext**

How can you do that with a batch file (.bat)?

Thank you for your help.

Addendum:
actually, if something like this would work for any files with any extensions together, that's the targeted result I am looking for:

copy (star).(star) (star).AA.(star)

Further more, I would be glad to take files with different extensions (let us say 1 pdf and 1 exe) together and to drag them on the batch file to have them renamed in the same directory with the ".AA" within.

Answer (score 2):

The COPY command uses the same rules for wildcards as RENAME - See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090).

No need for batch. You certainly can put the command in a batch file, but it isn't necessary.

```
copy filename.ext *.AA.ext
```

To copy multiple files

```
copy *.ext *.AA.ext
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. This simple line is very powerfull and works well for the given filetype. Would you know about a variation if instead of one filetype (e.g. ".ext") I would have e.g. a ".pdf" and a ".exe" (each to rename in ".AA.pdf" and ".AA.exe" resp.)? I tried a variation on your code but multiples extensions are not accepted by the dos cmd.

Comment: sorry, it works fine now :-/. What if I drag and drop the pdf and the exe on the ".bat" file to be renamed with AA? This is not accepted by the dos cmd. Code is now (but does not work with drag&drop): 
copy *.pdf *.AA.pdf
copy *.exe *.AA.exe

Answer (score 1):

I would start with something like this:

```
mkdir \tmpdir
copy filename.ext \tmpdir
mov \tmpdir\filename.ext filename.AA.ext
```

For something that works with multiple files...

```
mkdir \tmpdir
copy *.ext \tmpdir
mov \tmpdir\*.ext *.AA.ext
```

Comment: This will leave the tmpdir behind, and is way more complicated than is necessary.

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. It works fine for one file but the second version for multiple files does not work. Apparently the last line is not accepted, so the dos prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below achieve the process you want over all files that had been drag-and-drop'ed into it from the explorer.

```
@echo off
:nextFile
   if "%~1" equ "" goto exitLoop
   copy "%~1" "%~DPN1.AA%~X1"
   shift
   goto nextFile
:exitLoop
```

Antonio

Comment: Thank you very much. This works brillant with drag & drop and several files together with different extensions. There is only one point: the AA files are copied in the C:\Documents and Settings\%my path% directory and not in the same directory where the original files are. Any idea?

Comment: @johnsmith: Just insert a D and P letters before the N modifier in file name: `copy "%~1" "%~DPN1.AA%~X1"`. I already did that in the code above...

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!!

I answer my own question with the help of Antonio's solution. To add the path in the code and to get the copied files in the same directory, complete Antonio's code as following :

```
@echo off
:nextFile
   set filepath=%~dp1
   if "%~1" equ "" goto exitLoop
   copy "%~1" "%filepath%%~N1.AA%~X1"
   shift
   goto nextFile
:exitLoop
```

Now you can drag&drop several files with each having a different file extension and they will be copied in the same directory.

Thanks to everybody for your kind help!

Comment: Note that your solution copy all files to the directory of _first_ file. My solution below copy each file to its own directory, so you may mix files from different folders in the same drag&drop operation...

Comment: yes that is what I wanted: the whole operation shall happen within a given directory.